# Help with local coordinates with parents, constraints, and drivers

Tags: constraints, drivers, parent, coordinates

I'm trying to make a wheel rotation system using drivers

https://youtu.be/3mIrbZb-ZQQ

I have tried to fix this with drivers, constraints, and parents, all of them do the same thing.

Comment: What do they do? Why doesn't it work for you? What do you want instead?  Please flesh out your question so we can answer it.

Comment: You disable *Copy Rotation* constraint before showing the rotation around X works even if rotated around Z, but then you re-enable the constraint and show the rotation no longer works when "rotated by proxy". Therefore my guess is the constraint is the problem. It would be nice seeing the driver too. In general, it would be nice to have all the information available in the post rather than in the video that can get removed in the future, ideally with the showcase of the problem divided to multiple GIFs uploaded directly to SE.